# Display form text on another view Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am by no means a JavaScript or Vue.js developer and my knowledge is limited in this field but our developer has left us, so I am giving it a bash.

This I imagine is a simple question, I need to display the data saved from input fields on a registration form to display in another Vue as text.

Below are the fields from the form that the data must be pulled from.

Below is the data & method structure.

```
data () {
return {
  activeTab: 'general',
  account: {},
  showByIndex: null,
  daycation: {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    listing_type_id: '',
    phone_number: '',
    e_mail: '',
    adult_price: 0,
    child_price: 0,
    infant_price: 0,
    pensioner_price: 0,
    latitude: '',
    longitude: '',
    map_address: '',
    region_id: '',
    business_id: '',
    media: null,
  },
  open_weekdays: [],
  alert: {
    class: '',
    show: false,
    message: ''
  }
}

},

methods: {
    getDaycation: function () {
      this.$http
        .get('my-daycations/edit/' + this.$route.params.uuid)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.body.error) {
            console.log(res)
            return
          }
          this.daycation = res.body.daycation
          this.open_weekdays = res.body.daycation.open_weekdays.length > 0 ? res.body.daycation.open_weekdays : []
          this.opening_time = res.body.opening_time
          this.closing_time = res.body.closing_time
          this.latLng = {
            lat: parseFloat(res.body.daycation.latitude),
            lng: parseFloat(res.body.daycation.longitude)
          }
        })
        .catch(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
    },
    saveDaycation: function () {
      this.hideAlert()
      this.$Progress.start()
      this.$validator.validateAll().then(result => {
        if (!result) {
          this.$Progress.fail()
          return
        }
        this.daycation.open_weekdays = this.open_weekdays
        let data = this.daycation
        this.$http
          .put('my-daycations/edit/' + this.$route.params.uuid, data)
          .then(res => {
            if (res.body.error) {
              this.$Progress.fail()
              this.showAlert(
                result.body.message,
                'alert-danger',
                'error_outline'
              )
              return
            }
            this.$Progress.finish()
            this.showAlert(
              'Daycation has been updated.',
              'alert-success',
              'check_circle_outline'
            )
            window.scrollTo(0, 0)
          })
          .catch(res => {
            console.log(res)
            this.$Progress.fail()
          })
      })
    },
    showAlert: function (message, cssClass) {
      this.alert.class = cssClass
      this.alert.message = message
      this.alert.show = true
    },
    hideAlert: function () {
      this.alert.show = false
      this.alert.class = ''
      this.alert.message = ''
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getDaycation()
    this.avatar = localStorage.getItem('_user_avatar_url')
  }
}`
```

and here is where the input field data must be printed

```
 <p class="mt-0 mb-0">Email <strong>{{daycation.e_mail}}</strong></p>
    <p class="mt-0 mb-0">Phone <strong>{{daycation.phone_number}}</strong></p>
```

With its data and method structure.

```
data () {
    return {
      longDescription: false
    }
  },
  methods: {},
  created () {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depends on what do you mean by "another view". If you mean another component (I hope so) there is a few options.

If another component is a child of main component you can use props -
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

If another component is a parent you can use emit - https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201

And if you don't mind using another library you can use Vuex (I think its the best option in your case) - https://flaviocopes.com/vuex/

In this case you must define **store**, **getters** and **actions** with **mutations** (it's not as complicated as it seems):

Which will be like this:

```
export default function () {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      email: '',
      phone: ''
    },
    getters: {
      EMAIL: state => state.email,
      PHONE: state => state.phone
    },
    mutations: {
      SET_EMAIL: (state, payload) => {
        state.email = payload
      },
      SET_PHONE: (state, payload) => {
        state.phone = payload
      },
    },
    actions: {
      SAVE_EMAIL: (context, payload) => {
        context.commit ('SET_EMAIL', payload);
      },
      SAVE_PHONE: (context, payload) => {
        context.commit ('SET_PHONE', payload);
      }
    },
  })

  return Store
}
```

Then you can set the value in store like this:

```
this.$store.dispatch(
  "SAVE_EMAIL",
  'my email'
);
```

And show it in the component like this:

```
{{this.$store.getters.EMAIL}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Justice47, I will try this now.

Comment: @J3DI13 have you succeeded?

Comment: I have not unfortunately, I gave it a try but failed. Thinking I need to brush up on my JavaScript a bit more which frustrates as this is the last item on the list. Thanks for following up @Justice47